# Python: sum up the score1 and score2 fields for all dicts inside the list which have the same teamA and teamB?

Tags: python-3.x

I have no ideas with counting the dictionary in a list. 
just like the list of instances

we have a list like this

```
list_of_dict = [{'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': '0', 'score2': '1'},
    {'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': '0', 'score2': '1'},
    {'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'},
    {'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'},
    {'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'},
    {'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'}]
```

I expect after counting output like lists under

```
list_of_dict = [
{'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '2'}
{'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': '3', 'score2': '0'}
]
```

Comment: first of all, don't use the word 'list' for a varible.

Comment: So you want to sum up the score1 and score2 fields for all dicts inside the list which have the same teamA and teamB?

Comment: `count the dicts in a list` is not correct description of your problem/desired outcome

Comment: if an answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list_of_dict = [{'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': '0', 'score2': '1'},
    {'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': '0', 'score2': '1'},
    {'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'},
    {'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'},
    {'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'},
    {'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict, dtype=np.int8)
new_df = df.groupby(['teamA','teamB']).sum().reset_index()

new_list_of_dict = new_df.to_dict('records')

print(new_list_of_dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': 3, 'score2': 0}, {'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': 1, 'score2': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

[@umn 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56129489/6698642) is more elegant and may be more optimized, so prefer that if you can use `numpy` in your script. Below is a simple way to do so without additional libraries:

```
list_of_dict = [{'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': '0', 'score2': '1'},
    {'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': '0', 'score2': '1'},
    {'teamA': 'Ocean Gaming ', 'teamB': 'PSISTORM Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'},
    {'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'},
    {'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'},
    {'teamA': 'Jin Air Green Wings ', 'teamB': 'Invictus Gaming', 'score1': '1', 'score2': '0'}]

intermediate_dict = {}

for d in list_of_dict:
    key = (d['teamA'], d['teamB'])
    if key in intermediate_dict.keys():
        intermediate_dict[key][0] += int(d['score1'])
        intermediate_dict[key][1] += int(d['score2'])
    else:
        intermediate_dict[key] = [int(d['score1']), int(d['score2'])]

final_list = []
for k,v in intermediate_dict.items():
    temp_dict = {}
    temp_dict['teamA'] = k[0]
    temp_dict['teamB'] = k[1]
    temp_dict['score1'] = v[0]
    temp_dict['score2'] = v[1]
    final_list.append(temp_dict)

print(final_list)
```